# ¿Hay un selector para elementos padres en CSS?

Tags: css

Quiero editar el css de un elemento al hacer hover a una etiqueta `<a>`.

Este es mi HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="menu-admin-elemento col-6">
      <div>
        <div class="menu-admin-img-contenedor">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <h2>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi SCSS:

```
@import '../../../../styles.scss';

.container {
  .row {
    .menu-admin-elemento {
      div {
        .menu-admin-img-contenedor {
          img {
            /*
              Quiero editar el css de este elemento utilizando
              la propiedad hover de la <a> de abajo.
            */
          }
        }
        h2 {
          a {
            &:hover {
            }
            /*
              Editar el CSS de .menu-admin-img-contenedor > img
              haciendo hover a <a>
            */
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no se puede y ademas no tiene sentido en tu caso. Deberias volver a plantear la estructura o a lo sumo utilizar javascript para apuntar a la img a partir del hover del ancla.

Comment: ´Tal vez deberías de cambiar la etiqueta css por scss en tu pregunta

Comment: Con "editar" el css de un elemento al hacer hoover a otro elemento te refieres a que por ejemplo al pasar el mouse sobre el hiperenlace se ponga un borde negro sobre la imágen?

Answer (score 0):

No, css no permite hacer eso, tendrás que usar Javascript

`elemento.addEventListener('mouseove', () => { ... })`

Comment: ¿Cómo solucionaría ese código JS el problema de la pregunta? Simplemente es un controlador de evento `mousemove`, ¿cómo se seleccionaría el padre del elemento?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conseguir el efecto que quieres haciendo trucos en CSS.
Puedes poner el contenedor `div.menu-admin-img-contenedor` debajo del `h2`, después cambias el estilo del contendor con el :hover en el enlace de la siguiente forma:

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasgL67s/21/)**

Como puedes ver al poner el `h2` encima puedes actuar sobre el contenedor (`div.menu-admin-img-contenedor`), y para conseguir lo que quieres, simplemente cambias el orden de los elementos (necesitas usar un sistema de posicionamiento fluido).

[Aquí tienes más información.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector#answer-36118012)

**NOTA:** Selectores para elementos padre me temo que no habrá hasta la siguiente versión de CSS.